# Controlling Spring Boot graceful shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, shutdown, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

Is there a way in Spring Boot to control the *graceful shutdown* of the app?

I know that you can have `@PreDestroy` methods in beans, but how can you control the ordering in which those `@PreDestroy` methods are called?

You can have multiple beans depending on each other will the shutdown of the context look for this dependency already and call the `@PreDestroy` methods in the right order or not?

For example what I would like to accomplish is:
1) stop listening for new requests on rest endpoints
2) prevent rabbit message listeners to accept new messages
3) wait for all processing that has started before the shutdown but is not finished yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Spring Boot 2.3.0** has added support for *graceful shutdown*.

You can enable graceful shutdown by setting up `server.shutdown=graceful` property.

To configure the *timeout* period you can use:

```
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=20s
```

[Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-graceful-shutdown)

---

If you cannot upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3, then you can check the below project:

- https://github.com/gesellix/graceful-shutdown-spring-boot